# Get next 8 rows from database on button click using linq to sql and web method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, linq

I am creating a webpage in which I fetch top 8 rows from database on page load. I put load more button on my bottom of my web page. What I want is when I click on load more button it shows me next new 8 rows and skip previous records and if there is no new record found then show me nothing. 
Below is my code which I was trying but it was repeating same duplicate records.

```
//Below event is fetching top 8 rows on page load
    function viewAllEvents() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Event.aspx/viewEvents",
            data: null,
            contentType: "Application/json; charset=utf-8",
            responseType: "json",
            method: "POST",
            success: function (response) {
                var x = response.d;
                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    $("#tabss > .event-container > .row").append(
                            "<div class='col-md-3'><div class='event'><div class='eventsimg'><img src= " + '../MediaUploader/' + x[i].EVE_IMG_URL + " alt=''></div><div class='event-content'><h3 class='title'>" + x[i].EVE_NAME + "</h3><p>" + x[i].EVE_DESCRIPTION + "</p><input type='button' id=" + i + " class='btn btn-pri' style='padding: 9px 9px;font-size: 12px;' onClick='eveReq(" + i + ", " + x[i].ID + ", " + x[i].EVE_CAT_ID + ");' value='Send Request' /><input type='button' class='btn btn-pri' style='padding: 9px 9px;font-size: 12px;margin-left: 2px;' value='Read More' /></div><div class='links clearfix'></div></div></div>"
                        );
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.status);
            },
            Failure: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }
//Below event is for when load more button is clicked
    function addTabs() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "Event.aspx/addTab",
            data: null,
            contentType: "Application/json; charset=utf-8",
            responseType: "json",
            method: "POST",
            success: function (response) {
                var x = response.d;
                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    $("#tabss > .event-container > .row").append(
                            "<div class='col-md-3'><div class='event'><div class='eventsimg'><img src= " + '../MediaUploader/' + x[i].EVE_IMG_URL + " alt=''></div><div class='event-content'><h3 class='title'>" + x[i].EVE_NAME + "</h3><p>" + x[i].EVE_DESCRIPTION + "</p><input type='button' id=" + i + " class='btn btn-pri' style='padding: 9px 9px;font-size: 12px;' onClick='eveReq(" + i + ", " + x[i].ID + ", " + x[i].EVE_CAT_ID + ");' value='Send Request' /><input type='button' class='btn btn-pri' style='padding: 9px 9px;font-size: 12px;margin-left: 2px;' value='Read More' /></div><div class='links clearfix'></div></div></div>"
                        );
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.status);
            },
            Failure: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

Below is my web methods:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<EVENT> viewEvents()
{
     var slist = new List<EVENT>();
     var db = new BLUEPUMPKINEntities();
     db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
     slist = db.EVENTS.OrderByDescending(eve => eve.ID).Take(8).ToList();
     return slist;
}

[WebMethod]
public static List<EVENT> addTab()
{
    var slist = new List<EVENT>();
    var db = new BLUEPUMPKINEntities();
    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    slist = db.EVENTS.OrderByDescending(eve => eve.ID).Skip(8).Distinct().ToList();
    return slist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I didn't use your code but I believe if you can go through this example below then you'll know what to do:

First declare a global variable which will count the record returned so far:

```
private int recordCount = 0;
```

Then in the click event do the following:

```
 //My sample data 
 int[] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

 var results = data.Skip(recordCount).Take(2);

 //Increment recordCount by the count of the results return above
 recordCount+= results.Count();

 if (results.Count() > 0)
 {
    //return results 
 }
```